# Using "is" to refer past event

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

I heard once my Boss salary.
"My Nephew came from US, *He is sitting next to my seat* and enjoyed front seat driving view. In US it is no allowed"

My question is *He is sitting next to my seat* Using "is" to refer past event is correct or Not?

Comment: Did you mean "I once heard my boss **say**"?

Comment: Do you know how to conjugate the verb "to be"? If not, then please research it. If so, then please clarify why you're confused. Past tense events normally require past tense verbs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not present tense used to refer to a past event, but present tense used to talk about a general (but temporary) fact.

The boss means "He was and will be sitting next to me *whenever we are in a car together for the duration of his visit*"

It is a bit poorly phrased since he/she is switching between tenses chaotically but such poor phrasing is common enough in spoken English. The switch from "He's sitting" to "enjoyed" is particularly jarring.  If this was writing, I would edit to improve the phrasing (and fix the other mistakes like the comma splice and incorrect use of "no allowed")